# Field with unlimited length in Django

Tags: django

My generated form has this input field, with a default length of 254.

```
<input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
```

Generated by this Django code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!-- Render the field label tag -->
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    <!-- If the field is required, display a * next to the field label -->
       {% if field.field.required %}
       {% endif %}<!-- Render the input field -->
       {{ field }}<!-- Iterate over the field's errors, if any and display them one by one in a error alert-->
       {% if field.errors %}
           <p class="error">
           {% for error in field.errors %}
            {{ error }}
           {% endfor %}
         </p>
       {% endif %}
```

How can I get rid of the length limit?

Comment: I want to customize the django defult input field in password reset form.

Comment: I dont need the maxlengthe  for the field how can i remove that .? 
by defult django provide a maxlength.but in my design the input field need in full length

Comment: Please edit your question instead of comenting it. It would help if you posted the `Form` declaration in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the `max_length` parameter for the `EmailField` in your `Form` class:

```
from django import forms

Class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=1000)
```

Though, as your database in all likelyhood requires a length specification for the field you will not be able to specify an unlimited length.